# Maven error reguarding war files & pom.xml

Tags: maven, pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>com.my.ssat</groupId>
    <artifactId>myssatProject</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>
  <artifactId>myweb</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>myweb</name>
</project>
```

- Cannot access default field of properties
- web.xml is missing and  is set to true.

I am getting these errors whenever I create maven module in (war) format

Comment: More details, create  step ? jdk version ? maven version ? create in IDE or terminal ?

Comment: Project created in sts, jdk 17, maven 3.8.6.

Comment: `web.xml is missing and is set to true.` , you can add this to pom.xml `<build>
  <plugins>
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>    
    </configuration>
</plugin>
  </plugins>
  </build>`

Comment: You need a example web war, `File` -> `New` -> `Other` -> `Maven` -> `Maven Project` -> **Select project name and location**,  Button **Next**, **Select an Archetype** ,  Filter: input `maven-archetype-webapp`, enter,  select Group Id: `org.apache.maven.archetypes`
Artifact Id: `maven-archetype-webapp`, button **Next**, input your Group Id: com.my.ssat ,Artifact Id: myweb2 , button **Finish**, Look up STS IDE bottom **console**, when it appear `Y:`
Move cursor to console, click, Enter **Y**, Press Enter. It will create a simple web project. Please reference this project's pom.xml.